Query a SQL Server using VB.Net for part of a Date Field to remove precision
We have a table that is logging events and the original programmer saved the timestamp as a standard Date.Now to the database so a event will have a timestamp such as 2024-10-23 11:53:18.110.  I've been tasked with adding a monitoring function that would read the database every minute and query it to email out critical events.  Since I will only be polling each minute I'm worried about missing a event since they are stored with such precision so I was going to round the events to the nearest whole minute and then my app would poll the last minute each time.  So for the example above when it runs at 11:54 it would poll for anything matching 2024-10-23 11:53.
With that said I'm having trouble creating a simple SQL statement since I do not want to pull everything and cycle through.  Is there a easy way to write a WHERE statement that can do the "pairing down" of the Date field on the SQL server side to just the hour and minute without modifying the database.  If not I can probably create a view on the server but I'm trying to avoid that.  Or we can modify how the events are saved in the first place and remove some of that precision.  But if there is a select statement I can use instead I'd like to.
For example I'd like to do something like this
Dim myFullDate As Date = CDate(Date.Now.ToShortDateString + " " + Date.Now.AddMinutes(-1).ToShortTimeString)
Dim myParamList As New Dictionary(Of String, Object) From {
                        {"@myDateTime", myFullDate}
                        }
Dim myEvents As DataTable = RetrieveData("SELECT [Name], [DateTime], [Description],[Severity] WHERE [DateTime]=@myDateTime", myParamList)

But make sure [EventDateTime] is also pared down to match my pared down last minute and I cannot figure out the syntax.  Or would it be better to just create a view in SQL and make it a string and just compare strings?
EDIT: Not sure why this is marked as a duplicate as I'm not trying to compare only the date.
Answered by Richard Deeming in comments.  I will just keep track of LastPolled as a variable and use that to poll everything after that each time, updating it as I poll the database.  This way if I miss a polling for whatever reason it won't matter as it will be accounted for.

"Rounding" dates isn't normally the way to query them. Instead you should be using inclusive ranges with >= and < logic. This create a SARGable query, and ensure you don't miss anything in the range.

Bear in mind that Windows is not a "real-time OS"; even if your query-and-send-mail process always takes less than a minute, you cannot guarantee that it will run on the minute every minute. Better to keep track of the last time it ran, and query for events logged since then ([DateTime] > @LastCheck).

This is not really the way to do monitoring. Let's say your app takes 3 minutes to run or takes a pause, because there's some query blockage or someone forgot to pay the electic bill, then you will miss all events except for the last minute events. What you usually do is to store last queried datetime somewhere and then start from that date

Although I agree that I should query based on last time queried this service is only doing this task and one other monitoring task and the emailing portion is running asynchronously.  I'm not really worried about missing a interval or running for more then a minute, in testing the longest runtime we had was less then 2 seconds.  With that said it might still make sense to do it as @RichardDeeming suggests and leave the full precision in.  Probably be simpler that way also.

None of your options are correct. The correct thing to do is to use a half-open range interval like @ThomA said, see also https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common and linked duplicate. WHERE DateTime >= @startDate AND DateTime < @endDatePlusOne

@Charlieface - No, Richard Deeming suggesting is correct and is the easiest option.  I just need to poll for the events that haven't been checked which can be accomplished by what he suggests.  I was only looking for the last minute because I am running once a minute.  But if I keep track of the last poll time then even if I miss a minute it doesn't matter.

Well the point is the same: don't use = equality, use >=

Yes, [EventDateTime]>=@LastPolledTime and update LastPolledTime immediately before the SQL call (the variable, not the parameter being passed)

What happens when monitoring computer restarts? You write something about variables
